# How to pass parameter with On Tap action versus Navigate To action

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

How can I pass page parameters without using the Navigate To action?

I'm trying to update a row but FlutterFlow's documentation specifies passing parameters using the Navigate To action that I'm trying to avoid. My goal is to set page parameters on click of a database entry to load the selected row on a separate window on the same page. My understanding is that this would require a custom action but I'm not familiar with Flutter, Dart, or custom code in FlutterFlow.

[Here's an example from FlutterFlow's docs on passing parameters through navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L62b9.png)

FlutterFlow's docs show:
Page 1 -> send parameter value -> Page 2

I am trying to:
Page 1 -> send parameter value -> Page 1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a Page State instead?

Page Parameters require you to pass data from another page, while Page States can be updated on the same page. Since you want to update something that is on the same page, it would make sense to store your desired value in a Page State and update it once you have clicked on the appropriate database entry.